# What is the logical order of load methods of UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

What is the logically executed order of a UITableViewController's methods when a segue is performed to show the tableView? Here is my best guess:

1. `viewWillLayoutSubviews`
2. `numberOfSectionsInTableView`
3. `numberOfRowsInSection`
4. `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
5. `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
6. `viewDidLoad`
7. `viewWillAppear`
8. `viewDidAppear`

Please correct this ordering and add to it.

Comment: At WWDC the engineers mentioned how we should never architect our apps around the assumption of which methods will be called first. Its bad practice and definitely not a future proof architectural decision. I strongly recommend against it

Comment: Ok that does make sense.

Comment: Put breakpoint and note down calling method in sequence

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may help you.

1. `viewDidLoad`
   As it loads view first.
2. `viewWillAppear`
   As any view appears again then this method is called.
3. `numberOfSectionsInTableView`
   Sets number of sections in a table.
4. `numberOfRowsInSection`
   After setting sections,this method determines number of rows in a section.
5. `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
   Height for row will be set.
6. `viewWillLayoutSubviews`
   View for section header is made.
7. `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
   Contents and layout of cell of a tableview is created in this method.
8. `viewDidAppear`

Comment: The two proposed answers don't match :\ Can any of you guys provide a link for future reference? And also edit  your answer if you end up being the one in the wrong

Comment: View delegate methods and TableView delegate methods, are two totally different things. I just explained them as flow goes on and referring View Delegate Method's references,  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html  & https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/  might help you.

Comment: Well either way, just comparing 1 2 & 3 shows a difference. One of you must be mistaken or am I not seeing something?

Comment: Mate I mentioned methods which are there in question and described them as I found flow in my project or any sample project. Correct me if any mistake is there in my delegate method flow.

Answer (score 8):

If you have 1 row and 1 section. This is the pattern it goes through.

1. viewDidLoad
2. numberOfSectionsInTableView
3. viewWillAppear
4. numberOfSectionsInTableView
5. numberOfRowsInSection
6. heightForRowAtIndexPath
7. viewWillLayoutSubviews
8. numberOfSectionsInTableView
9. numberOfRowsInSection
10. heightForRowAtIndexPath
11. viewWillLayoutSubviews
12. viewDidLayoutSubviews
13. viewDidAppear

Comment: The two proposed answers don't match :\ Can any of you guys provide a link for future reference? And also edit  your answer if you end up being the one in the wrong

Comment: I made a sample app to make sure the flow. This was the flow if you return 1 section and  1 row in a UITableViewController.

Comment: Where is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? When is it called?

Comment: and also `viewForHeaderInSection`?

Comment: In my scenario number of rows-->Cell for row --> Image picker --> did finish picking images --> tablview.reload()-->no of rows-->View will Appear(this is where i got the error) --> Cell for indexpath